# Guardar mejor puntuacion en un juego

Tags: c

Tengo que guardar la mejor puntuación obtenida de un juego hecho en C en un fichero: las funciones que puedo utilizar son `fopen`, `fclose`, `fprintf`,`fscanf`. He intentado hacerlo así:

```
int puntos=0;;;
if (lo que sea)
{
puntos=puntos+1;
}
 FILE * f_mayor_puntuacion = NULL;
    f_mayor_puntuacion = fopen("record.txt","r");
    int recordactual=fscanf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"%d",&recordactual);
    fclose(f_mayor_puntuacion);
    if (puntos>recordactual)
    {
        f_mayor_puntuacion=fopen("record.txt","w");
        fprintf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"El record actual son %d puntos",puntos);
        fclose(f_mayor_puntuacion);
    }
```

El problema es que la variable `recordactual` es siempre 1, por lo que el fichero siempre se actualiza con los puntos incluso si no ha logrado la mayor puntuacion, y no se me ocurre otra forma de hacerlo. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu planteamiento es necesario hacer 2 actividades que ya has identificado. La primera es leer el puntaje, actualmente lo haces con la siguiente instrucción:

```
int recordactual=fscanf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"%d",&recordactual);
```

Lo anterior está mal, la función **fscanf** lee los datos del archivo de acuerdo al patron del segundo parámetro **"%d"** y almacena el valor en el tercer parámetro **&recordactual**, en este caso lee un número. El problema es que al mismo tiempo estas guardando el resultado de la función **fscanf** en la misma variable en la que pretendes alamacenar el puntaje **recordactual**, la función **fscanf** NO retorna el valor leído sino el número de items que pudo leer y que concordaron con el patrón, este uso indebido hace que el valor leído del archivo sea reemplazado por el valor devuelto por la función, por eso siempre la variable **recordactual** termina con el valor **1**. En resumen la forma correcta de leer el valor es:

```
fscanf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"%d",&recordactual);
```

La segunda actividad es escribir el valor siempre y cuando el puntaje sea mayor al anterior, observo que lo haces con la siguiente instrucción:

```
fprintf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"El record actual son %d puntos",puntos);
```

Lo cual en general no está mal, sin embargo tengo una observación, y es que estás guardando en el archivo un mensaje con el puntaje, este mensaje no cumple con el estandar original del archivo que es solo un número, es decir que en la próxima ejecución el archivo no podría ser leído correctamente, adicionalmente esto no generará un error, pero afectará tu programa por que el valor leído siempre será cero al no poder la función **scanf** encontrar un patrón numérico en los datos leídos.

Haciendo todo el ajuste de acuerdo a lo que te menciono, el programa debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: No entiendo, si hago esto  `fscanf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"%d",&recordactual);` , ¿como se supone que inicializo la variable recordactual?

Comment: @paradise85 si observas bien el tercer parámetro incluye el modificador de dirección **&** esto le da la habilidad a la función **fscanf** de modificar o colocar el valor leído en la variable **recordactual**, por lo tanto esta se inicializará con el valor leído del archivo, no es necesaria una inicialización manual de tu parte.

Comment: Si hago lo que tu me has dicho, el programa no compila: error 'recordactual' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @paradise85 claro, cualquier variable que uses en el programa deberá ser declarada antes de hacer cualquier operación, al inicio de tu función o programa deberás declararle **int recordactual;** mira que ni es necesario darle un valor inicial para este caso

Comment: Vale, ya me funciona. Respuesta marcada y gracias por todo =)

Answer (score 0):

Por la forma en que lees el archivo, creo que el problema es lo que escribes en él. Solo deberías escribir el puntaje:

```
fprintf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"%d",puntos);
```

Comment: El problema es que tengo que escribir eso solo cuando supere el recordactual, y eso no sé como hacerlo

Comment: Eso parece que ya lo estás haciendo con `if (puntos>recordactual)`...

Comment: No entiendo, si no leo el fichero, ¿ entonces como inicializo recordactual?

Comment: un detalle, fscanf devuelve en el segundo parametro lo que ha leido en el archivo. Es decir, estas sobreescribiendo puntos. deberias cambiarlo por **fscanf(f_mayor_puntuacion,"%d",&recordActual);**

Comment: He intentado hacer eso también pero sigue sin funcionar (aunque si hago eso recordactual pasa a ser 1 siempre en vez de 0)